# linking Labjack C++ libraries to the c++ code

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I want to attach a  .lib file to my c++ code. The library name is : LabJackUD.lib and I have tried using terminal with a -lLabJckUD and -lLabJackUD.lib but no avail. Pls help..

Comment: Where is the library file located? What is the *exact* command you use? And `LabJckUD`?

Comment: it is located in the same folder as the c++ file.
And the exact command was :  g++ allio.cpp -lLabJackUD
or
g++ allio.cpp -lLabJackUD.lib
Both gave the same error

Comment: You should provide us the error message you get.

Comment: The error message :

C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLabJackUD.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: What is the exact command you are using?

Comment: Exact command is :
g++ allio.cpp -lLabJackUD

Comment: LabJackUD is the name of the external library that i need to use to run the code on a device connected to my Pc

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `-l` (lower-case L) option causes the linker to look in a number of predefined locations. It does *not* look in the current directory.

To make the linker look in a specific non-standard location you need to use the `-L` option. As in

```
g++ allio.cpp -L. -lLabJackUD
```

Or use the library-file directly as an input file:

```
g++ allio.cpp LabJackUD.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command as below:

```
g++ allio.cpp LabJackUD.lib
```